# iTextSharp - PDF Bookmark not pointing to a page

Tags: c#, itext

I have built a tree view to show the bookmarks of a given PDF document.

Using iTextSharp I get the bookmarks in a List object and use the Title value to show on the tree view, no problem.

The problem comes when I want the tree view node to reference a page number in the PDF document.

Some PDF documents have a value for Title, Page and Action for example:
**Title:** "Title Page",
**Page**: "1 XYZ -3 845 1.0",
**Action**: "GoTo"

However, others are in this format:
**Title:** "Title Page",
**Named:** "G1.1009819",
**Action:** "GoTo"

I have no idea what to do this the "Named" value. I have tried going through all the links in the document and comparing the value to the destination value of the link, but with no luck.

Does anyone know what this "Named" property represents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a named destination, see [the keyword list](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=102) for some examples. It is a very common way to mark destinations in a document.

What do you want to do with the named destinations?

Do you want to `consolidateNamedDestinations()` so that they are no longer named destinations, but links to the specific place in the document.

Or do you want to create a link to a named destination? (That's probably more work. I don't think there are examples at hand.)

If you browse [the examples](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=102), you'll discover the `LinkActions` where we use the `SimpleNamedDestination` object to retrieve the named destinations almost the same way you retrieve bookmarks using the `SimpleBookmark` class.

This code snippet gives us the bookmarks in the form of an XML file:

```
public void createXml(String src, String dest) throws IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    HashMap<String,String> map = SimpleNamedDestination.getNamedDestination(reader, false);
    SimpleNamedDestination.exportToXML(map, new FileOutputStream(dest),
            "ISO8859-1", true);
    reader.close();
}
```

See [destinations.xml](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter07/destinations.xml) for the result.

The code is much easier because the structure isn't nested: each name corresponds with a single destination.

Comment: Would it be possible to get a page number from the named destination?

Comment: Hmm... Apparently you didn't read my answer. I'll update it and make it more explicit.

Comment: Appologies, on the second try it made perfect sense!  I used the consolidateNamedDestinations() method and it showed the page numbers.  Thanks for the help, much appreciated :)

Comment: That is certainly the solution that requires the least number of code lines. Using `SimpleNamedDestination` would work too, but it requires more code. In any case: my answer is more complete now, and that's also a good thing.